# Making an enemy follow checkpoints

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I'm making a game and using tile maps. On the tile maps are little checkpoints "c1, c2, c3, c4, ect". How would I make it so the enemy goes to c1 then c2 and so on in perfect order then goes back up them? Like a pathfinding system in a way. I'm using Java in the eclipes

Comment: There is absolutely no way somebody could answer your question without knowing anything about your game code.  Also, I don't think people are willing to essentially write your game for you for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could basically have a queue of commands for your object.  Break the "go to c4" to 4 distinct commands: "go to c1", "go to c2", "go to c3", "go to c4".  The object would grab the next command in the queue and follow it to completion, then get the next command, and so on til all were done.

Google "command pattern" for more info and a more general explanation.